# Is the following statement provable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-functions

The statement is: $f$ is a real fucntion on $\mathbb R$. Then if $f'(x)=f(x)$ and $f(0)=1$, then $f(x)\neq 0.$

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it's provable.  Unless I'm mistaken if $f'(x) = f(x)$ for all x in R it is provable that there is one and only one possible function for $f$ and that particular function $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Please show me then. And I assume we don't know anything about exponential function and hence anything about its properties. But of course, if you can show that the two conditions in some way are the defining properties of a function, and then you show that this function is positive, then it's acceptable.@fleablood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another solution — this one doesn't require knowing about the exponential function.

We're given that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, $f'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $f(0)=1.$

Assume that there is some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a) = 0$.  We must have $a \ne 0$ since $f(0)=1.$

Note that, since $f$ is differentiable, it must be continuous.

Claim 1: There exists $b \ne 0$ such that $f(b)=0$ and there are no zeros of $f$ between $0$ and $b$.

Proof of Claim 1: If $a \gt 0$, take $b$ to the the greatest lower bound of $\lbrace x | x \gt 0$ and $f(x)=0\rbrace$.  If $a \lt 0$, take $b$ to the the least upper bound of $\lbrace x | x \lt 0$ and $f(x)=0\rbrace$. In either case, $f(b)=0$ by the continuity of $f$.  Notice that $b$ can't equal $0$, since $f(0)=1$. There are no zeros of $f$ between $0$ and $b$ by the choice of $b$, proving Claim 1.

Since $f$ is continuous and $f(0)=1$, there exists $d$ with sign opposite that of $b$ such that there are no zeros of $f$ between $d$ and $0$; hence there are no zeros of $f$ between $d$ and $b$.  Let $I$ be the open interval between $d$ and $b$.

Claim 2: For every $x \in I$, $f(x/2)^2=f(x)$.

Proof of Claim 2: Define $g(x)=\frac{f(x/2)^2}{f(x)}$.  The function $g$ is defined on $I$ since $f$ has no zeros there.  Differentiating $g$ and using the fact that $f'=f$, we find that $g'(x)=0$ for $x \in I$.  It follows that $g$ is constant on $I$.  But $0 \in I$ and $g(0)=1$, so $g$ must be identically $1$ on $I$, proving Claim 2.

Now we use continuity again.  If $b \gt 0$, then $$0 = f(b) = \lim_{x \to b^{-}} f(x) = \lim_{x \to b^{-}} f(x/2)^2 = f(b/2)^2.$$ If $b \lt 0$, then $$0 = f(b) = \lim_{x \to b^{+}} f(x) = \lim_{x \to b^{+}} f(x/2)^2 = f(b/2)^2.$$  In either case, $f(b/2)=0,$ contradicting the fact that $f$ has no zeros between $0$ and $b.$

Comment: A nice proof indeed-but it seems like way too much work for such a simple result. And it's highly unlikely anyone who could answer the question would have never seen the exponential function. That being said, it's good to know for completeness that if you didn't,you could still prove it.

Comment: The OP said in a comment that he was looking for a solution without explicitly using the exponential function.  (Of course, this solution essentially proves some properties of the exponential function.)  I don't know if there's an easier way to do it -- you can use $\frac{f(x+c)}{f(x)}$, where $c$ is a constant, instead of the $g$ I used, but I don't think it really simplifies the proof.

Comment: The OP didn't ask this in the original question,only a follow up comment. The original question's what I was working off of. You're right,without explicitly using the exponential function,this gets a lot tougher. That being said,I'd like to try and find a nice short proof that doesn't explicitly use $e^{x}$. I think you implicitly used the intermediate value theorem in your proof,did you?

Comment: I'm using the fact that $g'=0$ implies that $g$ is constant, which comes from the mean value theorem.  Other than that, I think I'm just using basic properties of continuity and simple rules for taking derivatives.  (By the way, my first answer used the exponential function since that seemed like the natural thing to do based on the actual question, and then I saw OP''s comment, so I figured out this other approach.)

Comment: One addition: the proof uses the completeness of the real numbers (for existence of the glb or lub in Claim 1).  But completeness is *the* fundamental property of the real numbers, so it appears, at least implicitly, in almost all arguments involving the real numbers.

Comment: BTW there is an easier approach as described in my answer.

Comment: Nice proof, @ParamanandSingh.  Not having to divide by $f(x)$ simplifies things considerably.

Comment: In recent past I wrote some blog posts on the theory of exponential and logarithmic functions and hence I explored many ways to introduce these functions and the current question is the first step to develop a theory of $e^{x}$ from $f'(x) = f(x), f(0) = 1$. See http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html for more details. Moreover since you intuitively knew that $f(x) = e^{x}$ you could have replaced $g(x) = e^{-x}f(x)$ of your another answer with $g(x) = f(-x)f(x)$ and reached my solution.

Comment: So you were almost close to my answer. +1 for both answers.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the statement is provable and moreover *it is provable without any knowledge of $e^{x}$*.

Consider the function $g(x) = f(x)f(-x)$ and then we can see that $$g'(x) = f'(x)f(x) - f(x)f'(-x) = f(x)f(-x) - f(x)f(-x) = 0$$ and hence $g$ is constant. Then $g(x) = g(0) = f(0)f(0) = 1$. Thus $f(x)f(-x) = 1$ for all $x$. It follows that $f(x)$ is non-zero for all $x$.

Using similar approach you should try to prove the following:

*If $f'(x) = f(x)$ for all real $x$ then either $f(x) = 0$ for all values of $x$ or $f(x) \neq 0$ for all values of $x$.*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good way of seeing this, knowing basic facts about the exponential function:

Assume that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, $f'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $f(0)=1$.

Then $g(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-x} f(x)$ is differentiable, since it's the product of differentiable functions.

Applying the product rule, $g'(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-x} f'(x) - \mathrm{e}^{-x} f(x).$  But this equals $\mathrm{e}^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))$, which is $0$ because of the assumption that $f'(x)=f(x)$.

Since $g'(x)$ is identically $0$, $g(x)$ must be a constant function.  We have $g(0) =  \mathrm{e}^{-0} f(0) = f(0) = 1$; since $g$ is a constant function, $g(x)=1$ for all $x$.

By the definition of $g$, we now know that $\mathrm{e}^{-x} f(x) = 1$ for all $x$.  It follows that $f(x)$ can never be $0$, since something times $0$ can't equal $1$, completing the proof.

By the way, how do we know that $g'$ being identically $0$ implies that $g$ is a constant function?  Apply the mean value theorem: Suppose there were two distinct numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $g(a) \neq g(b)$. Without loss of generality, $a<b$ (if not, switch $a$ and $b$). Then there exists $c$ such that $a < c < b$ and $g'(c) = \frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}$, which is non-zero, contradicting the fact that $g'$ is identically $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Well,it should be clear that what we actually have here is a differential equation with 3 initial conditions
1) For every $x\in\mathbb R$, f'(x) = f(x).

2)f(0)=1.

3)  For every $x\in \mathbb R$, $f(x)\neq 0$

We need to test all 3 conditions on any candidate function. So let's integrate both sides:

$\int f'$ = $\int f $  $\rightarrow$ f(x) +c = $\int f $.

The 2 initial conditions are really what solves the problem. The only closed form real valued function that satisfies all 3 of these conditions is f(x) = $e^{x}$. Verify as follows: f'(x) = 1* $e^{x}$ = $e^{x}$. Also f(0) = $e^{0}=1$. 
Also, for every $x\in \mathbb R$, $e^{x}\neq 0$.

So the real valued function that satisfies all 3 conditions is f(x) =  $e^{x}$ and that ends the proof.

Comment: Thanks, but I was not asking for solving the ODE given that you already know exponential function. I was asking if one can prove condition 3 given condition 1 and condition 2 without knowing anything about the exponential function.

Comment: @NicholasLiu To "prove" this result,all you really needed to do was show that a real valued function exists that satisfies all the conditions and I did that. Why make it more complicated then it needs to be?